# C# List containing users and company break apart by company

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting a list of users from AD and now I'm trying to sort them by the company they work for and send them in an email to that company.

My list of users looks like

```
WSDA Jon Smith
WERT James Smith
WSDA Jim Smith
WEDJ Dave Smith
and so on...
```

I also have a list of the companies

```
WSDA
WERT
WEDJ
so on...
```

What is the best way for me to loop through the list of users and separate them by company?

```
List<string> msgBody = new List<string>();
List<string> stations = new List<string>();

            PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.com");
            UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(AD);
            PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(u);
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
            DateTime lastLogon = new DateTime();

foreach (UserPrincipal result in search.FindAll())
            {
                lastLogon = result.LastLogon ?? DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan difference = todayDate - lastLogon;


                if (difference.TotalDays > 90 && result.PasswordNeverExpires == false && result.EmailAddress != null)
                {
                    msgBody.Add(string.Format("{0} {1} {2} ", result.GetProperty("company"), result.DisplayName, result.LastLogon));

                    if(stations.Contains(result.GetProperty("company")) == false)
                        stations.Add(result.GetProperty("company"));
                }

                search.Dispose();
            }



public static String GetProperty(this Principal principal, String property)
    {
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
        if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(property))
            return directoryEntry.Properties[property].Value.ToString();
        else
            return String.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at List.GroupBy.

Comment: Are you looking to send one email per company?

Comment: yes I am and the email will be to company@domain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GroupBy is made for this sort of thing.

```
var usersByCompany = users.GroupBy(u => u.CompanyName);
foreach(var grouping in usersByCompany)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Company: " + grouping.Key);
    foreach(var user in grouping)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  User: " + user.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using first (assuming you have an email field available on your object) you can group by Company then select the email property of the first record from every grou.

```
List<string> companyEmails = userListName.GroupBy(user => user.Company).Select(u => u.Email.First()).ToList();
```